# How can I add icon or a html on select2 selected option not from the option list

Tags: php, laravel-5, jquery-select2

What I want to achieve is 
[image]

It work perfectly fine if i select one option from list of options.
But on update I want to set it manually not with javascript but from html when the page loads. The option value is dynamic.

```
<option value="1" selected><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Rakesh shrestha</option>
```

here the name Rakesh Shrestha and the value = 1 is dynamic.. I'm using php.
It is escaping my html i only get

```
<option value="1" selected>Rakesh shrestha</option>
```

and hence no icon.

Select2 init:

```
$('.allSiteSelect2').select2({
        width : "100%",
        placeholder : 'Site',
        escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
            return markup;
        },
        templateResult: function(data) {
            return data.text;
        },
        templateSelection: function(data) {
            return data.text;
        },
        ajax : {..}
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us your PHP Code that is creating this HTML?

Comment: no its not php code that creating the HTML... think of it as I want to select this in the beginning.  ` <option value="1" selected><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Rakesh shrestha</option> ` @ascsoftw

Comment: So which value you want to be selected automatically. Since `value="1"` will always change, how do you identify the option.

Comment: I mean in an update.. i need to have one value selected